# Iframe stretch to full height of parent div with float positioning

Tags: html, css, iframe, layout

I have a page that has 2 halfs a document viewer, and form. I am using a float to position the form next to the document view. My problem is that the document viewer, which is an iFrame, won't stretch to the full height of the parent div, so it is the same length as the form. How do I make the iFrame match the height of the form?

Thanks in advance for any help. I know my codes not perfect.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fsvoqeum/

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.box .box-content {
  overflow: auto;
}
.box-head {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.form-view {
  width: 46.5%;
  margin: 1.5%;
  height: 93%;
  display: inline;
}
.thHeader {
  width: 300px;
}
.thNo {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.verify {
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
  width: 46.5%;
  margin: 1.5%;
  height: 93%;
}
```

```html
<div w id="container">
  <div class="shell">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-head">Process Forms</div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div class="verify">
          <h1 style="color:black;"><b><u>Verify Upload</u></b></h1>
          <h1 style="color:black;">Volunteer:
            <br>
            Form Type:<br><br>
          </h1>
          <form>

            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <th>Tool</th>
                <th class="thHeader"><span>Yes (1)</span><span class="thNo">No (2)</span>
                </th>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 1</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="first" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 2</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="second" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 3</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="third" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 4</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="fourth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 5</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="fifth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 6</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="sixth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 7</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="seventh" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 8</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="eighth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 9</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ninth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 10</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="tenth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 11</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="eleventh" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 12</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="twelvth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 13</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="thirteenth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 14</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="fourteenth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

          </form>

        </div>
        <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=http%3A//www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/filemanager/files/Documents/Anschiss%20nach%20dem%20Nettoeinkommen.pdf" class="form-view" width="100%"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy if `flexbox` is an option for you:

1. Give `display:flex` to the `box-content` (maybe consider swapping the positions of `verify` and `form-view` or using `row-reverse`)
2. Remove the height, width and float styles and give `flex:1` to the flexbox children - `form-view` and `verfiy`

Demo below:

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.box .box-content {
  overflow: auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
}
.box-head {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.form-view {
  /*width: 46.5%;*/
  margin: 1.5%;
  /*height: 93%;*/
  /*display: inline;*/
  flex:1;
}
.thHeader {
  width: 300px;
}
.thNo {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.verify {
  overflow: auto;
  /*float: right;*/
  /*width: 46.5%;*/
  margin: 1.5%;
  /*height: 93%;*/
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div w id="container">
  <div class="shell">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-head">Process Forms</div>
      <div class="box-content">
        <div class="verify">
          <h1 style="color:black;"><b><u>Verify Upload</u></b></h1>
          <h1 style="color:black;">Volunteer:
            <br>
            Form Type:<br><br>
          </h1>
          <form>

            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <th>Tool</th>
                <th class="thHeader"><span>Yes (1)</span><span class="thNo">No (2)</span>
                </th>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 1</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="first" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 2</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="second" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 3</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="third" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 4</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="fourth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 5</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="fifth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 6</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="sixth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 7</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="seventh" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 8</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="eighth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 9</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ninth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 10</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="tenth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 11</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="eleventh" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 12</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="twelvth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 13</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="thirteenth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tool 14</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="fourteenth" size=4 maxlength=1>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

          </form>

        </div>
        <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=http%3A//www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/filemanager/files/Documents/Anschiss%20nach%20dem%20Nettoeinkommen.pdf" class="form-view" width="100%"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```